# How to grab Textfield input values with Redux-form using MaterialUI

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, material-ui, redux-form

Goal: Get the input values from a  material UI component and pass them to an action creator in a handleSubmit function.

```
                 <Field name='email'
                  component={email =>
                   <TextField
                    fullWidth
                     autoComplete='off'
                      className={classes.textField}
                      id='email-text-field'
                      label='Email'
                      value={email} />
                    } />

                 <Field name='password'
                  component={password =>
                    <TextField
                      type='password'
                      fullWidth
                      autoComplete='off'
                      className={classes.textField}
                      id='password-text-field'
                      label='Password'
                      value={password} />
                    } />
```

This is how it is being connected to Redux:

> @reduxForm({form: 'loginForm', fields: ['email', 'password']})

The warnings I'm getting in my chrome dev tools console is:
 Failed prop type: Invalid prop `value` supplied to TextField.
 Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `value` supplied to Input.`

Additionally, the email field in my login form shows [Object, object}
My guess is that this is happening due to the fact that props are  being passed from the

Any ideas on where I've gone wrong?

Comment: The `value` prop *sets* the value of the field.  It seems that you want to retrieve it, so you should be looking at the `onChange` handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to use a custom field for Redux-Form, Redux-form gives you access to both props like `onChange` etc, **but also other meta-data** (like if the form has been touched or not). These different kinds of **props are grouped depending on type**.

The interesting part for you is that all the attributes associated with a normal input element (like `onChange`, `value`, `type`) are grouped in `props.input`. So the argument you call `password` is actually the whole `props` object that is sent down to the component. It looks something like this `{input:{ value: 'someValue', onChange: somFunction..  etc. etc}, meta: { touched: false, etc. etc.}}`.

That means that if you want to use the `TextField` like you do now, you need to do something like:

```js
<Field name='email'
    component={({input}) =>
      <TextField
         value={input.value}
         onChange={input.onChange}
         fullWidth
         autoComplete='off'
         className={classes.textField}
         id='email-text-field'
         label='Email'
        />
     } />
```

This can get pretty messy, especially if you want to use the `meta` props, so it's often worth it to break the custom component logic out into its own function, like they do in the example in the docs: https://redux-form.com/7.0.4/examples/material-ui/

You may also be interested to know that for `material-ui` components, there actually already exists a [library that has done most of that manual work for you: `redux-form-material-ui`](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form-material-ui).

Comment: Great! I was able to get the form values in the redux form reducer. I also tried using the redux-form-material-ui library but got a bunch of errors with the toggle button (which I was not making use of) from the library. It might be because I'm using a different version of material ui

Comment: Nice! Yeah,  differences between versions can be tricky. I would think that the `redux-form-material-ui`  should work "right out of the box" , as long as you import the `TextField` components etc. from `redux-form-material-ui` like they do in the example here: https://github.com/erikras/redux-form-material-ui   . But maybe not.